# While trying to train the model I am getting ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the code.

While trying to run this file, I am getting ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am using tensorflow 1.9

https://github.com/satyenrajpal/Concrete-Crack-Detection/blob/master/Train_CD.py

Here is the code I am trying to run.

Comment: Stack Trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Train_CD.py", line 320, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "Train_CD.py", line 317, in main
    model.optimize(num_iterations)
  File "Train_CD.py", line 268, in optimize
    sess.run([self.optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
      np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\ysj30\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this problem usually arises from having a one or more entries in your array that is not the same length as the rest, so essentially the array isn't seen as a valid matrix, but rather a 'sequence' of arrays that differ in length.

Try debugging the code and making sure that all the elements of your array are the same shape, I haven't looked through all your code, so I'm not sure if you intentionally want to feed sequences to your model, but in that case you should look into padding your data before inputting it, so that all the elements in your array are of the same length.

There are ample options for doing something like this, can't list them all off the top of my head, but one that comes to mind, that I've personally used before is [tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences) (that links to API v1.6, but it's also available in v1.11, just checked now)